# How to convert scientific notation double to non scientific notations double

Tags: c#, double, scientific-notation

I have a double that shows scientific notations like this: 2.95E-05
I get those values from a JSON string as double directly. I wonder how the double can be converted so it instead shows all zeros like a normal number? (0.0000295)

Below attempt does not work and still shows: 2.95E-05

Thank you!

```
 double value = 2.95E-05;
 value = double.Parse(value.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
 MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this and it depends on whether you want fixed precision or padded with 0's.

```
double value = 2.95E-05;
value = double.Parse(value.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:F10}",value));
Console.WriteLine($"{value:F10}");
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("F10}"));
Console.WriteLine($"{value:0.##########}");
```

Please take a look at the following to ascertain how to format numeric values, it's all you need to know and more. Although there is a lot of information here, the easiest way is too look at the examples:

- [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)
- [Custom numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)